# How to apply grid properties from parent to a particular child in tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, config

We use a modular approach with config files for our react project. So it goes like this:
Component which draws input fields ->
config file which has a parent div and has imported fields file in it ->
fields file which has fields with their IDs, values, etc.

So the question is, how can I select a particular child from the parent div and give it for example `col-span-n`?

I want it to look something like this:
`grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 md:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-8 mb-6 (and here classnames that will change particular child)`

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this way:**

```
    const ParentComponent = () => {
      return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 md:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-8 mb-6">
          {config.map((childConfig, index) => (
           <div key={index} className="col-span-1 md:col-span-2 lg:col-span-3">
              <ChildComponent   />
           </div>
           
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
```